# Injecting fluent wait Cucumber always returning as null

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, dependency-injection, cucumber

I have a cucumber project that is using pico-container to inject the Webdriver, I want to do the same with my fluent wait. I am utilising POM design. I am always getting the error

```
CucumberRunner.runScenario » NullPointer Cannot invoke "org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait.until(java.util.function.Function)" because "this.wait" is null
```

I can't see why its returning that as I believe im initialising it.

In my Hooks class I am doing:

```
package stepdefinitions;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

import base.BaseClass;
import io.cucumber.java.After;
import io.cucumber.java.Before;

public class Hooks {
  WebDriver driver;
    BaseClass baseclass;

    public Hooks(final BaseClass baseclass) {
        this.baseclass = baseclass;
    }

    @Before
    public void bf() {
        baseclass.setDriver();
        baseclass.setWait(baseclass.getDriver());
        baseclass.navigateToURL();
    }

    @After
    public void af() {
        baseclass.getDriver().quit();
    }
}
```

Then in my BaseClass I have:

```
package base;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.time.Duration;
import org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;
import org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException;


import utils.TestUtils;


public class BaseClass {
  private WebDriver driver;
  protected static Properties prop;
  private Wait<WebDriver> wait;


  public BaseClass() {
        try {
            prop = new Properties();
      FileInputStream inputFile = new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/src/main/java/config/config.properties");
      prop.load(inputFile);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      System.out.println("file not found");
    } catch (IOException e) {
      System.out.println("io exception");
    }
  }


    public WebDriver getDriver() {
        return driver;
    }

    public void setDriver() {
      ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
      options.addArguments("headless");
      options.addArguments("--window-size=1920,1080");
      driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
    }

    public void navigateToURL() {
      driver = getDriver();
      driver.get(prop.getProperty("url"));
  }

  public Wait<WebDriver> getWait() {
        return wait;
    }

    public void setWait(final WebDriver driver) {
        wait = createFluentWait(driver);
    }

    // Helper method to create the FluentWait
    private Wait<WebDriver> createFluentWait(final WebDriver driver) {
        return new FluentWait<>(driver)
                .withTimeout(Duration.ofSeconds(TestUtils.ELEMENT_TIMEOUT))
                .pollingEvery(Duration.ofMillis(TestUtils.POLLING_INTERVAL))
                .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class, ElementNotInteractableException.class);
    }
}
```

And I am using it in my HomePage object:

```
package pageobjects;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Wait;

import base.BaseClass;

public class HomePage extends BaseClass {
    SharedPageObjects sharedPageObjects;
    WebDriver driver;
    Wait<WebDriver> wait;


  // Account Nav Bar Elements
  @FindBy(css = "[class=\"nav__top-inner\"]")
  WebElement accountNavBar;

  @FindBy(css = "[class=\"nav__top-type\"] > a:nth-child(1)")
  WebElement personalHeader;

  @FindBy(css = "[class=\"nav__top-type\"] > a:nth-child(2)")
  WebElement businessHeader;

  @FindBy(css = "[data-action=\"navigation--primary#signin\"]")
  WebElement loginButton;

  @FindBy(css = "[class=\"nav__top-account-item\"]:nth-child(2)")
  WebElement signupButton;

  @FindBy(css = "[class=\"nav__user-name\"]")
  WebElement navUserName;

  @FindBy(css = "[data-test-id=\"user\"]")
  WebElement navUserIcon;

  // Main Nav Bar Elements
  @FindBy(css = "[class=\"nav__main\"]")
  WebElement mainNavBar;

  @FindBy(css = "[data-test-id=\"evri_logo_made_for_you\"]")
  WebElement logo;

  @FindBy(css = "div:nth-child(2) > div > a")
  WebElement sendButton;

  @FindBy(css = "div:nth-child(3) > div > a")
  WebElement trackButton;

  @FindBy(css = "div:nth-child(4) > div > a")
  WebElement returnButton;

  @FindBy(css = "div:nth-child(5) > div > a")
  WebElement ourServicesButton;

  @FindBy(css = "div:nth-child(6) > div > a")
  WebElement parcelShopButton;

  @FindBy(css = "div:nth-child(7) > div > a")
  WebElement helpButton;

  @FindBy(css = "[data-test-id='basket']")
  WebElement basketIcon;

  @FindBy(css = "button#onetrust-accept-btn-handler")
  WebElement cookieAcceptButton;

  // Hero Elements
  @FindBy(css = "img.the-hero-banner__title-image")
  WebElement heroBanner;

  @FindBy(css = "[class=\"the-hero-banner__heading\"]")
  WebElement heroBannerHeading;

  @FindBy(css = "[class=\"tabs-card\"]")
  WebElement heroCard;


    // Constructor
    public HomePage(final WebDriver driver) {
      this.driver = driver;
      sharedPageObjects = new SharedPageObjects(driver, getWait());
      PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
  }

    public HomePage verifyHomePageElements(final Boolean loggedIn) {
        verifyAccountNav(loggedIn);
        verifyMainNav();
        verifyHero();
        return this;
    }

    public HomePage verifyAccountNav(final Boolean loggedIn) {

        List<WebElement> elementsToCheck = new ArrayList<>();
        elementsToCheck.addAll(List.of(accountNavBar, personalHeader, businessHeader));

        if (!loggedIn) {
            elementsToCheck.addAll(List.of(loginButton, signupButton));
        } else {
            elementsToCheck.addAll(List.of(navUserName, navUserIcon));
        }

        // Assert each element in list is visable by calling sharedFunction
        sharedPageObjects.areAllElementsVisible(elementsToCheck);
        return this;
    }

   }
```

In my HomePage if I was to initialise the fluent wait within the constructor it works fine. It just cannot seem to initialise from the before hook.

Any explanations greatly appreciated!